# Ruby on Rails get key by value from two dimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a two dimensional array that looks like this:

```
TITLETYPE = [['Prof.', '4'],
  ['Dr.', '3'],
  ['Mrs.', '2'],
  ['Ms.', '1'],
  ['Mr.', '0']]
```

I need to get the key for value 1 for example (which should be 'Ms.')
How should I go about doing that?

Comment: Do you want to get the key, based on the value? Or are you just trying to access the key directly?

Comment: This is not a [dictionary](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) or anything related to key-value-pairs, it's an [array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) of arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
TITLETYPE.select{ |x| x[1] == '1' }.first.first
```

---

### How this works

You can use [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)'s [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select) method to find the row you're looking for. Your rows ar arrays with two elements each (element 0 and element 1), so you need to look for the row in which the second element (element 1) is equal to the value you're looking for (which is the string `"1"`):

```
TITLETYPE.select{ |x| x[1] == "1" }
```

This will return an array with only one row:

```
[["Ms.", "1"]]
```

To get the first and only value from that array, use `Array`'s [`first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-first) method, which will return:

```
["Ms.", "1"]
```

Then, from that, obtain the first value from the two values with `first` again:

```
"Ms."
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Sorry i should have been more clear: i am getting the value '1' from the database, and i need to find it's corresponding value in the array (or whatever it is, what is it btw?)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, sounds like `Array#rassoc` is perfect for you.

```
TITLETYPE.rassoc('1')[0] # => 'Ms.'
```

See the documentation at [Ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-rassoc).

Answer (score 0):

More naturally, you should keep such information as a hash. If you often want key-to value, and key-to value is unique, then create a hash:

```
TYTLETYPEHASH = Hash[TYTLETYPE.map(&:reverse)]
```

and access it:

```
TYTLETYPEHASH['1'] # => 'Ms.'
```

or create a hash like:

```
TYTLETYPEHASH = Hash[TYTLETYPE]
```

and access it:

```
TYTLEHASH.key('1') # => 'Ms.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and resolved it by simply using something like this:

```
<% Array.each do |value| %>
```

and accessing each element using `<%= value[:keyname] %>`

i.e.

An array which looks like this (using .inspect)

```
  [{:id=>1, :title=>"ABC"}, {:id=>2, :title=>"XYZ"}]
```

can become a HTML selection/dropdown box with:

```
 <select name="ClassName[TargetParameter]">
    <% Array.each do |value| %>
      <option value="<%= value[:id] %>"><%= value[:title] %></option>
    <% end %>
 </select>
```